# CSS3: Transparent Rounded Corner Problem

Tags: html, xhtml, css

Site is located here: **[CLICK TO VIEW THE WEBSITE](http://bit.ly/9sjLoS)**

Here is an image of the problem: [image]

As you can see, using CSS3 `border-radius`, and `background: transparent` I was able to make what looks like a "cutout" from the div. The problem should be obvious that the corners are transparent as well.

I know I could just use an image and problem would be solved, but I want to use CSS3. I think there is probably some ingenious way to get around this problem, but I am not thinking of it. I do want to note that I am using css3pie.com to allow IE6 through IE8 CSS3 functionality.

Comment: I think in this case a image *would* be appropriate, esp. with the way you're trying to stitch together that background...

Comment: offtopic: clever use of the image and background gradient. for a moment I was wondering why the background resized when I enlarged the window on my high resolution screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky

This rules apply to the p tag

```
-webkit-box-shadow: #A3AFC6 0px -4px 0px 3px;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't even think about doing a box shadow.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the developer toolbar in Chrome...

On `div.middle_bg` set the height to 85px. Then set the background on the `p` tag inside it.

Comment: Which version of Chrome does it work for you in?

It doesn't work for me using Chrome 6.0.472.51 beta on OSX. It also doesn't work in Safari 5.0.1 on OSX. In both cases I see the cutout like shown above.

Comment: Oh... didn't notice that it had to be transparent. Disregard, I'm dumb :)